# What is an Egyptian mummy wrapped in?

Tags: word-request

Is there a more technical word than just bandage or linen bandage?

Or an (Ancient) Egyptian loanword?

Answer (score 1):

"Bandages" seems to be the most common word in both technical and elementary writing. A rather more technical word is "swathings", though this is used less often, even in academic works.

According to the [ancient Egyptian dictionary](https://www.um.es/cepoat/egipcio/wp-content/uploads/egyptianhierogly.pdf), the Egyptian word was *auti*, *aru*, or *utaut*. But none of these are used as borrowed words in English.

[image]
[image]
[image]